# Statics in constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I was reading the OCPJP (SCJP) book, when I came across this question in chapter 2.

```
class Uber{
 static int y= 2;
 Uber(int i){
    this();
    y = y*2;
 }

 Uber(){
    y++
 }
```

}

```
class Minor extends Uber{
 Minor(){
    super(y);
    y=y+3;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    new Minor();
    System.out.println(y);
 }
```

}

The book says the answer should be 9, but I'm confused as to whether the compiler will recognize the y in super(y);. If it does how can that be?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: i think there must be class Minor extends Uber {

Comment: sorry again guyz, made another mistake, it should have had y++ in Uber(){}, this would make the answer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code you've given won't compile. It would compile if `Minor` extended `Uber` though - are you sure it doesn't in the book?

(Even after getting it to compile, the code prints 7 for me, not 9. I can't see how it would end up printing 9... it starts at 2, then is doubled to 4, then 3 is added to get 7...)

Comment: ah yes it does, sorry. Even so, will the compiler know that it's Ubers' y that it's refering to?

Comment: @Madz: Because those are the rules of the language... it's not private, so it's visible to `Minor`. Any accessible static variables up the inheritance hierarchy would be available.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Uber{
 static int y= 2;
 Uber(int i){
    this();
    y = y*2;
 }

 Uber(){
    y++
 }
}

class Minor extends Uber{
 Minor(){
    super(y);//this called uber class and it perfoms y =Y*2 so y contains now 4.
    y=y+3;//here y value becomes 7
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    new Minor();//it called minor class
    System.out.println(y);//It prints 7
 }
}
```

I comment your code.Where value y changes you can see that.